# threads to read file size in c (Mutex problem)

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, mutex

I have a project from school where we going to make a program with threads that are going to calculate the size of the files in a directory. We need to use lstat to get the block size of the file. My solution for this is to make all the threads, and the main thread is going to go through the directory and add each file that it finds to a queue. The threads can then take a file from the queue and get the block size with lstat. The picture is showing how I was thinking when I made this.
[image]

The program work's how I was expecting it to do. But the problem I have is that for each thread I add to the program the time that it takes to finish get's higher for each thread I add. So with one thread it takes 5 sec but with 2 threads it takes 7 sec.

I will show some of the code I made. I think I miss how I can use mutex here because the mutex block's the main to add to the queue and all the thread's get blocked when it adding to the queue. So if you see something that I miss with the mutex please tell me :).

```
/* If -j flag is used and it's more then 1 thread */
if(flag_j == 1 && threads > 1) {

    /* Create each thread */
    createThreads(th, threads);

    /* Make a task of each file and add task to queue */
    makeTask(argv);

    /* Tell that no more file will be added to the queue */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    endThreads = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    /* Join thread's */
    joinThreads(th, threads);
}

/**
 * Going to create all the thread's that was given
 * with the -j flag at start.
 * @param th An array of all the thread's.
 * @param threads The number of thread's.
 * 
 */
void createThreads(pthread_t th[], int threads) {
    for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        int *a = malloc(sizeof(a));
        *a = i;
        /* pthread create */
        if(pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &getQueue, a) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to create thread");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }    
    }
}


/**
 * Each thread will get a task from the queue to execute until
 * the queue is empty and the conditional variable is set to 1.
 * @param arg In this case it's NULL.
 * 
*/
void *getQueue(void *arg) {

    free(arg);
    while(1) {
        Task task;
    
        /* Lock */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if(queueCount > 0) {
            /* Get the first task in queue */
            task = queue[0];
            /* Move all the task in the queue forward one step */
            for (int i = 0; i < queueCount - 1; i++)
            {
                queue[i] = queue[i + 1];
            }
            queueCount--;
            /* execute the task */
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            execute(&task);
        } else if ( endThreads == 1) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            break;
        } else {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
    
    }

    /* The thread will just resturn NULL */
    return arg;
}


/**
 * Find the correct struct in the list of arguments.
 * Then add the size of the file to that struct and
 * add the struct back in to the list.
 * @param task Is the task that's need to be executed.
 * 
*/
void execute(Task* task) {

    int i = 0;
    char *path = malloc(1024*sizeof(path) + 1);

    /* Get the first name of the path */
    while (task->file[i] != '\0')
    {   
        /* Break when it find's the first "/" */
        if (task->file[i] == '/' && i != 0)
        {
             break;
        }
    
        path[i] = task->file[i];
        i++;
    }

    path[i] = '\0';


    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    for (int j = 0; j < numOfArg; j++)
    {
        Arguments entity;
        /* Get the first struct in listOfArg */
        entity = listOfArg[0];

        /* Move all the struct's one step forward */
        for (int k = 0; k < numOfArg - 1; k++){
            listOfArg[k] = listOfArg[k + 1];
        }
    
        /* Check if the struct name is the same name as the path */
        if (strcmp(path, entity.name) == 0)
        {
            /* Add the size of the file to the struct size */
            entity.size += getFileSize(task->file);
            /* Add the struct back to the list */
            listOfArg[numOfArg - 1] = entity;
            break;
        } else {
            /* Add the struct back to the list */
            listOfArg[numOfArg - 1] = entity;
        }   
    }

    /* Get the size of the file and add it to the total size */
    totalSize += getFileSize(task->file);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    free(path);
}

/**
 * Will check if the argument is a directory or an file.
 * If it is a directory it's going to open and get the file's.
 * If it is a file it will make a Task and add the file to it
 * and add the task to the queue.
 * @param argv An array of the argument's.
 * 
*/
void makeTask(char *argv[]) {
    while(argv[optind] != NULL) {
        if (isDirectory(argv[optind]))
        {
            filesDir(argv[optind]);
        } else {
            Task t;
            t.file[0] = '\0';
            strcpy(t.file, argv[optind]);
            addTask(t);
        }
    
        optind++;
    }
}

/**
 * Will add the task to the queue of task for the thread's
 * to execute.
 * @param task The task to add to the queue of task's.
 * 
*/
void addTask(Task task) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    queue[queueCount] = task;
    queueCount++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: Please do ___not___ post images of code — post the code itself.  We can't see the code easily on phones; we can't work with the code from images on laptops or desktops.  (I recommend deleting the question while you fix it up, replacing the images with the text of the code, then undeleting it.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include all text **as text** instead of showing screenshots. Show your [mre] as **one** code block unless having separate files is necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Disks don't get faster when there are multiple threads contending to read them.  Slowing down with more threads is expected.

Comment: Threads are unlikely to speed up calls to lstat() because lstat() is doing almost no cpu-bound work; what it does is read information from the disk (or from the file system cache if possible) and write it into your struct, which means the speed of processing is going to bottlenecked by the disk I/O performance no matter how many or few threads you employee.  Adding more threads just adds overhead to that bottleneck.

Comment: I change the pictures to code. The program is going to calculate the size the file's take on the disk. When you add more thread's it is going to do it faster then one thread is going to do it. That's what the teacher told me.

Comment: Your teacher told you wrong.  Adding more threads does not automatically make things run faster.  If the bottleneck is the CPU, then adding more threads can speed things up provided the costs of coordination between threads are small enough.  If the bottleneck is the disk system, adding more threads won't speed up the processing.

Comment: What they want is that each thread is going to take a file and not use the same file as the other threads have used. So say we have 4 thread's then each thread is going to take a file(not the same file) from the directory that was given at start. Then each thread is going to use lstat on the file that. What they told me is that this is going to make the program go faster to a certain point. One student have already finish this and told me that it is going to go faster.

Comment: Why are you allocating memory in `createThreads()` that you just free again without use in `getQueue()`?  Just pass `NULL` instead.

Comment: I did just test a thing thats why. It is just passing in the number on the thread.

Comment: As already pointed out twice, this approach will not make your program run faster. The point is that reading directories and retrieving file sizes is IO-bound with little CPU. Understanding the difference between IO-bound and CPU-bound is the key here. Also, threads only speed up things when they allow distributing work to different workers, like multiple CPUs, harddrives or network interfaces. If your teacher says using multiple threads speeds up things without explaining why and when, it's a bad teacher.

Comment: Your threads can only access the queue one at a time and access to the queue is horribly inefficient because of all the copying involved. Then all your threads just fight over access to the same filesystem data. This is not an operation that it makes any sense to parallelize, at least not with this kind of approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments express valid concerns about which kinds of operations multithreading can speed up and which it can't, but they seem largely to have latched onto one plausible explanation for your observations without considering others.  I/O considerations *will* limit the gains achievable from parallelization, but operating systems implement measures to try to reduce the impacts of slow I/O, such as readahead and data and metadata caching.  Therefore, it is not necessarily the case that an I/O bottleneck will be sufficient to completely overcome all speedup from parallel computation in this case.  Your classmates' observations cannot be discounted here, though it is not necessarily safe to assume that their programs are correct, either.

In fact, there are multiple other issues with your code that contribute to poor multithreaded performance and scaling, including

- busy-waiting.  When `getQueue()` checks the queue and discovers it empty, it unlocks the mutex and then immediately attempts to re-acquire it.  That re-acquisition has a good chance to succeed despite other threads waiting for the mutex, such as the one that is trying to fill the queue.  The more worker threads you add, the harder it is for the main thread, running `makeTask()`, to queue tasks.

  This sort of problem is usually addressed with the help of a condition variable.
- Highly inefficient queue implementation.  Every time an element is removed from the queue, the whole tail of the queue is moved up so that the head is at index 0.  And all of this has to be performed while holding the mutex locked, reducing the proportion of the overall work that can run in parallel.  There are multiple better-performing alternatives -- a circular queue or a linked list, for example.
- The appearance of a second critical region in `execute()`.  It's unclear what all this manipulation of `listOfArg` is about, but it also limits the proportion of your program that executes in parallel.  And it has similar efficiency problems to those involved in manipulating the task queue.

The program also exhibits some general inefficiencies that probably don't make much difference to speedup and scaling, such as additional instances of shifting arrays around one element at a time via loops instead of via `memmove()`, hand-rolling string operations instead of using built-in, optimized library functions such as `strchr()`, and performing dynamic memory allocation where automatic allocation would serve better.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, it did help alot. Did miss that they are competing to use the queue. Maybe that main thread can send a signal when it have added something to the queue and then a thread can go in and get it.

Comment: *but operating systems implement measures to try to reduce the impacts of slow I/O, such as readahead and data and metadata caching*  But none of those will make multiple threads reading a directory and putting filenames into a queue any faster.  That's like using a bunch of people carrying small jars lining up to get water from a single faucet, fill their jar, then dump the water into a bucket.  The coordination isn't worth it when you can just put the bucket under the faucet and get it done much easier, and likely faster and with much less likelihood of having spilled water.

Comment: (cont)  3,000 people with 3,000 jars might be able to move water faster than the faucet can deliver it, but that's irrelevant.  Same thing here - all the treads in the world aren't going to dump names in the queue faster than they can be read from the directory by a single thread.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, in the OP's code, a single thread reads a directory and enqueues filename-containing tasks.  Other threads dequeue those tasks and do additional work with them, revolving around file metadata such as could be served from a metadata cache.  The overall system cannot go faster than tasks can be enqueued, but that does not imply that multithreading cannot provide a speedup, because more work overall is being performed than is required to enqueue the tasks.